# Making Jam with Fruit Pulp?

Tags: wine, fruit

[image: Mixed berry wine pulp]

As you can see I've got my mixed berry wine pulp. It has sugar mixed in and a liter of water. My question is: Can I use the pulp left over to make jam? Has anybody attempted this?

Comment: Little off topic for this forum, but related. I imagine you could add some gelatin and maybe corn syrup to make a jam

Comment: I'm planning on having a go tonight. I will post the results.

Comment: Strangely, I find that jam is a good way to store fruit/sugars for subsequent fermentation. Blackcurrant jam is a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an attempt at making the jam. It worked but sadly there was way too many seeds for it to be enjoyable and i don't have the equipment to remove them.

Comment: It must be difficult to calculate how much sugar is needed to make a good jam that is not too sweet.

Comment: And there isn't really much you can do about it as the sugar is already in the pulp.